# Why do dogs and cats produce allergens, and how will these shots work to prevent it from stimulating the immune system in humans?

Tags: cats, allergies

I found [a post](https://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/ny-swiss-scientists-develop-vaccine-for-cat-allergies-20190817-2trdtfxitvefla6ioujwqjliuq-story.html) early this morning when I did a Google search.

Part of this sentence doesn't make sense. It says that it works by immunising them against their own allergen. If they are not immune to them, why don't they get sick from inhaling their own dander?

Comment: The antibodies bind to the allergen for when a human comes in contact. It has no significant effect on the cat (in theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allergy symptoms are caused by the immune system reacting to something that's harmless. People that don't have the allergy don't have an immune reaction. Pets don't get sick from their own dander because of course they wouldn't naturally have an immune system reaction to their own bodies (well, unless they had some autoimmune disease.)

The immunization is training the pet's immune system to have an unnatural reaction to the allergen that causes the immune reaction in allergic people. It's more surprising to me that doing this doesn't cause the animal to have some sort of symptoms, as having the immune system react to your own body is the root cause of autoimmune disease. I can only conclude the allergen is non-essential to the animal.